# Need help in tag helper in Asp.Net core 1.0 (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am unable to make tag helper working ASP.Net core project in Visual Studio 2015. There is no compilation errors in the project. When I run the project the tag helper is not getting rendered. I put the break point in "Process" method in Tag helper, but it is not coming there. Please let me know how to make it work.

1.Included "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final" in "dependencies" section in "project.json" file.

2.Added @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers in _ViewImports.cshtml file.

3.Added below code in Index.cshtml

```
<table generate-rows="@Model.Count()" source-model="@Model"></table>
```

4.Tag helper code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;

namespace MVC_TagHelper.CustomTagHelper
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("table",Attributes ="generate-rows,source-model")]
    public class TableTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        [HtmlAttributeName("generate-rows")]
        public int RepeatCount { get; set; }
        [HtmlAttributeName("source-model")]
        public ModelExpression DataModel { get; set; }
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            IEnumerable model = DataModel.Model as IEnumerable;
            if (model == null)
                return;
            else
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var m in model)
                {
                    PropertyInfo[] properties = m.GetType().GetProperties();
                    string html = "<tr>";
                    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
                    {
                        html += "<td>" + m.GetType().GetProperty(properties[i].Name).GetValue(m, null) + "</td>";
                    }
                    html += "</tr>";
                    sb.Append(html);
                }
                output.Content.SetHtmlContent(sb.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `_ViewImports.cshtml`. Make sure it contains a reference to your tag helper class namespace:

```
@using MVC_TagHelper;
@addTagHelper *, MVC_TagHelper
```

I struggled with the same problem a while ago.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting error - Cannot resolve TagHelper containing assembly 'MVC_TagHelper'. Error: Could not load file or assembly 'MVC_TagHelper' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Project Name & Default Name space is MVC_TagHelper. Controller namespace is MVC_TagHelper.Web. Tag Helper name space is MVC_TagHelper.CustomTagHelper and its class name is TableTagHelper. _ViewImports.cshtml file - using MVC_TagHelper addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers addTagHelper *, MVC_TagHelper

Comment: @user1396423 this is because the assembly in which you implemented the tag helpers is not called `MVC_TagHelper`. (I put it that way because I assumed the name derived from `MVC_TagHelper.CustomTagHelper`). Change it to the correct assembly name and it should be it.

Comment: I tried sir, but still not working. I am not understanding what is wrong.

Comment: Are you getting the same error or is your taghelper being ignored again?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the same error- Cannot resolve TagHelper containing assembly 'MVC_TagHelper.CustomTagHelper'. Error: Could not load file or assembly 'MVC_TagHelper.CustomTagHelper' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I saw many videos in which they have used "ASP.Net 5 Template" to create the project. In my system even though I have Visual Studio 2015 am not seeing "ASP.Net 5 Template" option at the time of creating the project. Is that causing the problem ?

Comment: Versioning kinda sucks with these latest ASP.Net versions... As a last resort I would try re-installing the tools (everything except VS). But before that step, can you get us the full name of the assembly containing the `TableTagHelper` class? Just in case... so we can say that, maybe, there is a bug in the framework.

Comment: DotNet Framework tried 4.5, 4.6 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers 1.1.2  and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.1 with Visual Studio 2015. Added the TagHelpers through nuget package Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

Comment: Had the same problem but on VS 2017 (where they did away with project.json). I simply removed the reference in the .csproj file, and updated the TagHelpers package via nuget. That did it for me.